# ItemTouchHelper does not initiate swipe

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have looked up many tutorials on the swipe functionality to the RecyclerView. When I attach the ItemTouchHelper, it has no effect on the ViewHolder.

I had put a put a breakpoint in onSwiped method but it does not even reach there when I am trying to swipe. I made a new project and just implemented a random recyclerview with some view holders. I attached the ItemTouchHelper and I had the same problem.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[ViewModel::class.java]
    val dues = model.dues
    val adapter = Adapter<Due>(R.layout.card_view_dues, fragmentManager!!)
    dues.observe(this,
        Observer<MutableList<Due>> {
            adapter.list = it
        }
    )
    val itemTouchHelper = object: SimpleCallback(0, LEFT and RIGHT) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ) = false

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            dues.value?.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition) //set breakpoint here
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
    ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelper).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!.applicationContext)
        setHasFixedSize(false)
        this.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

I have also replaced:

```
ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelper).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

with

```
ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelper).attachToRecyclerView(activity!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView))
```

but it still doesn't seem to work. What has possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are supplying the wrong argument to SimpleCallback

```
    val itemTouchHelper = object: SimpleCallback(0, LEFT and RIGHT) {
```

instead you should

```
    val itemTouchHelper = object: SimpleCallback(0, LEFT or RIGHT) {
```